# WSO2 logging remot IP address in audit.log

Tags: wso2, audit, audit-logging

Does anyone know if it is possible to log in **WSO2**'s **audit.log** the user's IP address? What's the format I have to configure in repository/conf/log4j2.properties?
It works just fine in http_access*.log but I am unable to set it in audit.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the below to the `deployment.toml`

```
[audit.log.contextual_param]
params = ["remote_address"]
```

Besides the `remote_address` you can also add `user_agent` as a parameter or both at the same time.

Comment: It is logging the "remote address" but not what I need, the "X-Forwarded-For"

Comment: @StefanG AFAIK that's the best you can get.

Comment: YES! It is working! It requires the correct RemoteIpValve configuration in catalina-server.xml

Comment: In our case we had to add manually the configuration

     <!-- This configuration specifies enabling contextual param for audit logs. -->
     <LoggableContextualParams>
        <contextual_param>remote_address</contextual_param>
        <contextual_param>user_agent</contextual_param>
     </LoggableContextualParams>

in repository/conf/identity/identity.xml